# Google Apps Admin outside Origination

Tags: google-apps

I help a couple clients with their google apps accounts in setting up new users and editing groups. Is there a way I can set my google email address to be an admin of their account so I dont have to have my own account on their domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can access their Admin console and make changes if you resell the accounts and they don't [restrict access](https://support.google.com/work/reseller/answer/6184379). Other than that, you need to have a dedicated admin account on each.